# Get value of remote JS var with Jurassic Script Engine

Tags: javascript, c#, jurassic

My remote js file as below

```
(function(window,document){

    var config =  {
        'placeHolder' : 'content_div'

    };

    var html = "blaaa blaaa";

})(window,document);
```

I would likte to get value of html.
I have tried as below but I have got error.

```
  string _JsVars = this._HttpWebRequestRemoteUrl(@"http://www.remotewebpage.com");

  var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
  var result = engine.(_JsVars);
  var var1 = engine.GetGlobalValue<string>("html");

  MessageBox.Show(var1.ToString());
```

Comment: It is impossible since `html` is not in global scope.

Comment: @epascarello Actually this is the answer already, no need to make it a comment.